# Making All possible combinations of given set with predetermined length

Tags: python

Okay, so I have a list

> input: [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>
> output: [0000,0001,0010,0100,1000,0002...]

I came up with a really stupid way of doing that but I'm looking for something more efficient.

```
def makeMoves():
    combList = []
    moves = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
    while len(combList) < 1296:
        move = ''
        for i in range(4):
            move += random.choice(moves)
        if not move in combList:
            combList.append(move)
    return combList
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look at `itertools`.

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import permutations

inp = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
result = [''.join([str(x) for x in element]) for  element in permutations(inp, 5)]
```